# neo4j allPossiblePaths without passing from a particular node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple social graph, and I would calculate all possible Paths, without passing from some of my friends.

I'm new to cypher and I really can't understand how to put this condition in WHERE condition (or anywhere else)

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all the paths from person A to person B that do NOT go through person C?

Comment: Yes, it's exatly what i mean

Comment: It returns always 0 rows

Answer (score 1):

maybe (hesitant to put as answer due to likely bad performance):

```
MATCH p=(a:Person)-[:FRIENDS_WITH*]-(b:Person) 
where a.name='me' 
and b.name='you' 
and none(c in nodes(p) where c.badbreath='true')
```

Would take some indexes for decent performance - in general, for ALL databases, the concept of NOT IN is a very bad performer.

Maybe someone can take this answer and improve it...